# Parameters needed to create Outlook Appointments

Tags: outlook

I work with a document assembly program called XpressDox.  I am looking for the parameters needed to add an appointment to Outlook 2010.  The following application code which creates an Excel spreadsheet is being provided as an example. I wish to embed a similar code in a template that will create an Outlook appointment.

Sample Code:

```
«CreateObject(‘ExcelApp’, ‘Excel.Application:’)»
«CreateObject(‘Sheet’,‘ExcelApp:WorkBooks.Add.WorkSheets’,’Item’,1)»
«InvokeMethod(‘Sheet:Range(A1).Select’)»
«SetProperty(‘ExcelApp:ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1’,’Date’)»
«InvokeMethod(‘Sheet:Range(A2).Select’)»
«SetProperty(‘ExcelApp:ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1’,’2013-01-21’)»
«InvokeMethod(‘Excel.Application:ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs’,ExcelFileName)»
«InvokeMethod(‘Excel.Application:Quit’)»
```

Reference URLs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article describes the basics. The following articles provide sample code and describe how to create an appointment in Outlook programmatically:

- [How to: Programmatically Create Appointments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268752.aspx)
- [How to: Create an Appointment as a Meeting on the Calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861308.aspx)
- [How to: Create a Recurring Appointment that Occurs Every 2 Years](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869162.aspx)
- [How to: Programmatically Create a Meeting Request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268875.aspx)